# Rails 4 Remove Migration ID from Migration Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I remove a migration ID listing with "** NO FILE **" in rake db:migrate:status?  For example:

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20131017204224  Create users
   up     20131218005823  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20131218011334  ********** NO FILE **********
```

I'm not understanding why it would still keep an old migration file when I manually removed it myself as I was playing around with how migrations work.  Is this for record keeping?  But what use is it when I don't have a name associated with it?

I tried using db:migrate:down command for those files but it says file missing. I have no clue what to do here.

Can someone explain how to remove this listing and maybe some insight on why this might happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to delete that numbers from your `schema_migrations` table in the database.

Comment: Not to sound like I want the answer to be spoon fed but after looking into schema_migrations.. I'm guessing I'm suppose to reload the schema for it to rebuild?  I used this command `rake db:schema:dump` `rake db:schema:load` but the no file listings are still there.  I'm also guessing it's some kind of ActiveRecord::Schema method to delete a specific version in the database?

Comment: If you want to have a migration number be deleted from the `schema_migrations` table, than just run `rake db:rollback` to revert the migration, before deleting the file.

Comment: But what if I already removed the file before I ran the `rake db:rollback` command?

Comment: Than you did not follow Rails conventions. Shame on you. ;-)

Comment: Ah crap.. I figured that would've been the answer.  I only learned that after I started to tinker with migration commands :\ Ah well.. live and learn.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10):

You can also delete it using SQL, but through the rails console.

```
sql = "DELETE FROM schema_migrations WHERE VERSION = 'version_id'"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
```

Answer (score 9):

You deleted the file but the ID is still in the schema table.

*Just Log into mysql*

```
 SELECT * FROM schema_migrations; *- take note of the version_id*
```

*Then*

```
DELETE FROM schema_migrations WHERE VERSION = version_id;
```

*Then logout and verify*

```
rake db:migrate:status
```